# How to compute $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\arctan x}{1+(x+\frac{1}{x})\arctan x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculate the following integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\arctan x}{1+(x+\frac{1}{x})\arctan x} \, dx$$

But I have no way to do it, can someone help me, thank you.

Comment: Numerical approximations are pretty simple to achieve ($I\approx 0.122$). Are there some reasons for expecting a nice closed form?

Comment: *Note:* $\enspace$ E.g. an approximation of the integral with the *Riemann sum* $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{ \frac{kx}{n} \arctan\frac{kx}{n} }{n + (\frac{n^2}{kx}+kx)\arctan\frac{kx}{n}  }\enspace$ for large $\,n\,$  .

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio,Thank you for you help,I really want to ask the square integral, and I'd like to ask a new one.

Comment: @user90369,Thank you for you help,I really want to ask the square integral, and I'd like to ask a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through the [Shafer-Fink inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0753)

$$ I\geq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{\frac{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{3}+x^2+1}\,dx = 0.122039\ldots$$
$$ I\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{\frac{1+2\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\pi}+x^2+1}\,dx = 0.124451\ldots$$
but I do not see any particular reason for expecting a nice closed form.