# How to compute $\int_{0}^{1}\left (\frac{\arctan x}{1+(x+\frac{1}{x})\arctan x}\right )^2dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I want to calculate the following integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\arctan x}{1+(x+\frac{1}{x})\arctan x}\right)^2 \, dx$$

But I have no way to do it, can someone help me, thank you.

Comment: Previous episode: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606178/how-to-compute-int-01-fracx-arctan-x1x-frac1x-arctan-xdx

Comment: @Robert Z - Indeed. Though despite appearances, the two integrals are actually quite different.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this was downvoted?  It was negative until I upvoted it.  I had a great time trying and failing to solve this.

Comment: @BenB - I thought the same so gave it an upvote from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, there exists a closed-form expression for the indefinite integral (credit Mathematica, not me, for this):
$${-x^2+(1+x^2)(\arctan(x))^2\over 2(x+(1+x^2)\arctan(x))}\,,$$ as can be
verified by differentiation.  Integral over $x\in [0,1]$ is equal to ${\pi^2-8\over 8(2+\pi)}\approx0.0454529$.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a way to arrive at the answer, and it is by no means obvious.

In finding the indefinite integral the *reverse quotient rule* will be used. Recall that if $u$ and $v$ are differentiable functions, from the quotient rule
$$\left (\frac{u}{v} \right )' = \frac{u' v - v' u}{v^2},$$
it is immediate that
$$\int \frac{u' v - v' u}{v^2} \, dx = \int \left (\frac{u}{v} \right )' \, dx = \frac{u}{v} + C. \tag1$$

Now the indefinite integral 
$$I = \int \left (\frac{\arctan (x)}{1 + \left (x + \frac{1}{x} \right ) \arctan (x)} \right )^2 \, dx,$$
can be rewritten as
$$I = \int \frac{x^2 \arctan^2 (x)}{\left (x + (x^2 + 1) \arctan (x) \right )^2} \, dx.$$

Let $v = x + (x^2 + 1) \arctan (x)$. Then $v' = 2 + 2x \arctan (x)$. Now for the hard bit. We need to find a function $u(x)$ such that
$$u' v - v' u = u'[x + (x^2 + 1) \arctan (x)] - u [2 - 2x \arctan (x)] = x^2 \arctan^2 (x).$$
If 
$$u = \frac{-x^2 + (x^2 + 1) \arctan^2 (x)}{2},$$
then
$$u' = x + x \arctan^2 (x) + \arctan (x),$$
and we find, miraculously, that
$$u' v - v' u = x^2 \arctan^2 (x).$$

Our indefinite integral can now be readily found as it can be rewritten in the form given by (1). The result is:
$$I = \int \left (\frac{-x^2 + (1 + x^2) \arctan^2 (x)}{2[x + (x^2 + 1) \arctan (x)]} \right )' \, dx =  \frac{-x^2 + (1 + x^2) \arctan^2 (x)}{2[x + (x^2 + 1) \arctan (x)]} + C.$$

So for the definite integral on the interval $x \in [0,1]$ we have
$$\int_0^1 \left (\frac{\arctan (x)}{1 + \left (x + \frac{1}{x} \right ) \arctan (x)} \right )^2 \, dx = \frac{\pi^2 - 8}{8(2 + \pi)}.$$

Comment: Friend, thank you for this.  I spent half a day on this to no avail.

Comment: @omegadot  Well done! (+1)

Comment: @omegadot Thanks for your answer,but  I don't understand how that u came out of it?

Comment: @FofX - Conjuring up a function $u(x)$ such that in our case $u' v - v' u = x^2 \arctan^2 (x)$ was by no means easy and is what usually places very limits on the effectiveness of using the *reverse quotient rule* as a method of integration. Sometimes the method may be easy to apply where the function $u(x)$ can be more or less immediately found by inspection but in this particular case it involved a lot of trail and error. Perhaps there is an alternative method for finding this particular integral that is more "obvious" but I have so far been unable to find one.

Answer (score 2):

This is about as far as I got.  Let me know if anyone can finish this analytically:

$$
\left( \frac{\arctan x}{1 + (x + \frac{1}{x}) \arctan x} \right)^2 = \\
\left( \frac{\frac{x}{1 + x^2} \cdot \arctan x}{x \cdot \frac{1}{1 + x^2} + \arctan x} \right)^2 = \\
\left( \frac{x \arctan x  \cdot (\arctan x)'}{(x \arctan x)'} \right)^2
= \\
\left( \frac{(\arctan x)'}{[\ln(x \arctan x)]'} \right)^2
$$