# Find the indefinite integral $\int \left(\frac{\arctan x}{\arctan x - x}\right)^2 dx$.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am wondering if there is a systematic way to find the indefinite integral

$$\int \left(\frac{\arctan x}{\arctan x - x}\right)^2 dx.$$

It indeed has a clean closed form 
$$\frac{x^2 + 1}{\arctan x - x} + x.$$

But I am not able to reach it in a logical way. The transformation $t = \arctan x$ doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: Maybe transforming $\frac{\arctan x }{\arctan x - x}$ to $1+\frac{x}{\arctan x - x}$ might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand is
$$ \left(1+\frac{x}{\arctan x - x}\right)^2 = 1 + \frac{2x}{\arctan x - x} + \frac{x^2}{(\arctan x - x)^2} $$

Observe that
$$ (\arctan x - x)' = \frac{1}{x^2+1} - 1 = -\frac{x^2}{x^2+1} $$

So we can perform IBP on the last term

$$ \int (x^2+1)\left(\frac{1}{(\arctan x - x)^2}\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)dx = \frac{x^2+1}{\arctan x - x} - \int\frac{2x}{\arctan x - x} dx $$

Thus 
$$ \int \frac{x^2}{(\arctan x - x)^2}dx +  \int\frac{2x}{(\arctan x - x)^2} dx = \frac{x^2 + 1}{\arctan x - x} $$

The rest is obvious.

Answer (score 4):

To find the indefinite integral I will make use of the so-called *reverse quotient rule* (For another example using this method see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607796/how-to-compute-int-01-left-frac-arctan-x1x-frac1x-arctan-x/2609856#2609856)).

Recall that if $u$ and $v$ are differentiable functions, from the quotient rule
$$\left (\frac{u}{v} \right )' = \frac{u' v - v' u}{v^2},$$
it is immediate that
$$\int \frac{u' v - v' u}{v^2} \, dx = \int \left (\frac{u}{v} \right )' \, dx = \frac{u}{v} + C. \tag1$$

Writing the integral as
$$I = \int \left (\frac{\arctan (x)}{\arctan (x) - x} \right )^2 \, dx = \int \frac{\arctan^2 (x)}{(\arctan (x) - x)^2} \, dx,$$
we see that $v = \arctan (x) - x$. So $v' = -x^2/(1 + x^2)$. Now for the hard bit. We need to find a function $u(x)$ such that
$$u' v - v' u = u'(\arctan (x) - x) + u \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2} = \arctan^2 (x).$$
After a little trial and error we find that if
$$u = x\arctan (x) + 1,$$
as
$$u' = \arctan (x) + \frac{x}{1 + x^2},$$
then
$$u' v - v' u = \arctan^2 (x),$$
as required.

Our integral can now be readily found as it can be rewritten in the form given by (1). The result is:
$$I = \int \left (\frac{x \arctan (x) + 1}{\arctan (x) - x} \right )' \, dx = \frac{x \arctan (x) + 1}{\arctan (x) - x} + C.$$

Comment: Nice answer. It would be better if you showed me the deduction way of how to get the form of $u$, i.e., how to solve the differential equation involving $u$, with the difficulty less than solving the original problem.

Comment: @Zhanxiong - As I said in my answer, this is the hard bit. It requires a little bit of trial and error to see what works and is always one of the problems associated with trying to use the *reverse quotient rule* to find an integral. Sometimes the method may be easy to apply where the function $u(x)$ can be more or less immediately found by inspection but in this particular case, as I said, it involved a bit of trail and error. Perhaps there is an alternative method for finding this particular integral that is more "obvious" but I have so far been unable to find one.

Comment: thanks, let's wait for a little more to see if there are other solutions.