# Primitive of $\frac{1-a\cosh(x)}{(\cosh(x)-a)^2}$

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

I would like to solve the following primitive:

$$\int\frac{1-a\cosh(x)}{(\cosh(x)-a)^2}\,dx$$

where $a$ is a constant, $0\leq a\leq1$.

I really don't know how to start. I can't relate the numerator with the denominator. There's no $\sinh(x)$ in the integrand, and I can't see any similarity with the well known hyperbolic functions derivatives. How would you do it?

Comment: What does $$[…]$$ mean?

Comment: That's the same as $(...)$. It's there because I already used $(...)$ inside of it. I can change it to avoid confusion.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there is a way of evaluating this integral without "guessing" or "by inspection" arriving at the right answer first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly more structured approach to arriving at an answer which is not simply based, as you say, on a "pure guess."

Let
$$J = \int \frac{1 - a \cosh x}{(\cosh x - a)^2} \, dx.$$

To find the integral $J$, the appearance of the all squared term in the denominator of the integrand suggests it may be possible to make use of the so-called *reverse quotient rule* (For another example using this method see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084419/definite-integration-when-denominator-consists-of-x-sin-x-1/3085378#3085378)).

Recall that if $u$ and $v$ are differentiable functions, from the quotient rule
$$\left (\frac{u}{v} \right )' = \frac{u' v - v' u}{v^2},$$
and it is immediate that
$$\int \frac{u' v - v' u}{v^2} \, dx = \int \left (\frac{u}{v} \right )' \, dx = \frac{u}{v} + C. \tag1$$

For the integral $J$ we see that $v = \cosh x - a$. So $v' = \sinh x$. Now for the (generally) harder bit but in this particular case it is quite easy. We need to find a function $u(x)$ such that
$$u' v - v' u = u'(\cosh x - a) - u \sinh x  = 1 - a \cosh x.$$
After a little trial and error it is quite easy to see that if
$$u = \sinh x,$$
as
$$u' = \cosh x,$$
this gives
$$u' v - v' u = \cosh^2 x - a \cosh x - \sinh^2 x = 1 - a \cosh x,$$
where we have used $\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1$, as required.

Our integral can now be readily found. The result is:
\begin{align}
J &= \int \left (\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x - a} \right )' \, dx = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x - a} + C.
\end{align}
as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by conjecturing an antiderivative of the form $\frac{f(x)}{\cosh x-a}$, so $$f^\prime(x)(\cosh x-a)-f(x)\sinh x=1-a\cosh x=\cosh^2x-a\cosh x-\sinh^2x.$$By inspection, one solution is $f(x)=\sinh x.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate $$\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)-a}+C$$ with respect to $x$

Comment: I see that this is indeed the primitive of $\frac{1-a\cosh(x)}{(\cosh(x)-a)^2}$. The function $\frac{1-a\cosh(x)}{(\cosh(x)-a)^2}$ can be achieved by differentiating $\frac{\sinh(x)}{\cosh(x)-a}+C$ and using the identity $\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$. Did you get this result just by pure guessing?